# How to send session information in an HTML email

Tags: php, session, html-email

With PHP, I want to send a link into my clients' email so they can have access to a page on my website. This page will not be accessed by other users. So I plan to include some session information in the mail function.

I don't know how to go about it. Please kindly assist.

Answer (score 3):

You can't send session info through to the email, but I would recommend creating a special token that is stored in your database. You can generate the link in the email to include that special token, then validate against it to ensure they are who they say they are.